# Running a hook after node save, or another way to get the file name attached to a node

Tags: hooks, files, 9

We've a D9 site with a custom module which generates and saves CSS code. It takes the name of the file attached to a node, and generates CSS to set it as the node's background.

Initially, I tried getting the file name from `$node` in the `_node_presave` hook, but `$node` does not contain it. What it does contain is the `nid`. So we're using that with `$nodeContent = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid)` to load the node, which then allows for `$file = $nodeContent->get('field_cover_image')->entity;`.

I've gone through the list of available hooks to run this code after node save, but have not found anything that does the job. Doing this task in node_presave means the node has to be re-saved, without altering the filename after the initial save (else the filename used initially ends up in our CSS, and our solution doesn't work.)

Digging deeper, I found that the only place in the DB where the file name is available is in the `file_managed` table, and only as part of longer data string that I don't fully understand.

What is an efficient way to get the name of the file attached to a node field on initial node save, so we can use it to generate CSS real time, on the first run?

A solution where we somehow trick the system into doing a second save in the background works as an alternative.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I had a similar task and created a [module that generates TailwindCSS on thy fly](https://www.drupal.org/project/tailwind_jit). Might be an alternative solution

Comment: You might be able to use `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`, which runs after `hook_node_save()`: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/10